# RunProcess works but not StartExternalSession

Tags: warning-messages, external-calls, python

I'm using MMA 11.2 on Ubuntu 16.10. Any reason why

```
RunProcess[{"python", "myscript.py"}]
```

works, while

```
StartExternalSession["Python"]
```

returns

> `StartExternalSession::noinstall: No valid installations for language
>   Python were found with the options specified.`

?

`FindExternalEvaluators["Python"]` returns an empty square, `RegisterExternalEvaluator["Python", "/usr/bin/python"]` returns

> `RegisterExternalEvaluator::invalid: -- Message text not found -- (ExternalEvaluate`Private`reason)`

even though `/usr/bin/python` is the output from `which python`. Also, `python --version` returns  `Python 2.7.12` and I did install `zmq`.

Comment: Well, did you follow the info here? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConfigurePythonForExternalEvaluate.html

Comment: @user6014 Yes, I'll edit with more info.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out `zmq`, though it seemed to have been installed smoothly with `pip`, was not properly installed. Not sure why and I'm don't know exactly what I did to correct it. If someone faces the same issue, I would recommend trying in python `import zmq`; if the library is found, `StartExternalSession` should work.